# How do I import module?

Tags: python, python-import

The directory structure is as follows:

```
folder1
  __init__.py
  file1.py
  folder2
    file2.py
```

If I write file2.py as follows:

```
from folder1 import file1
```

I get the error `No module named 'folder1'`.

If I write file2.py as follows:

```
from ..folder1 import file1
```

I get the error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

How can I import file1 from file2?

Comment: The syntax would be `import folder1.file1` and you need to make sure that your python path is set appropriately.

Comment: Where is folder2's `__init__.py`? Do you have any?

Comment: @ElisByberi I didn't create `__init__.py` in `folder2` because folder2 is not imported, but I created it now. However, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from .. import file1
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

Comment: `import sys 
sys.path.append("..")` does it work now ?